# Passing two variables to one JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have completed if I pass a variable `id` but now I want to pass `name` to the same function when I click on a image. This is my code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i <friend_data.length; i++) {
                        results += '<div class = "clicker" id = "'+friend_data[i].id+'" onclick="javascript:testId(this.id,'+ friend_data[i].name+')"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture" height="30" width="30">' + friend_data[i].name + '</div>';
                    }
```

and

```
function testId(id, friend_data[id].name ){
    alert(id);
    alert(friend_data[i].name);     
}
```

The `alert(friend_data[i].name);` does not show because it's wrong. Please help me to correct it.
Please look in even `onclick` it's the right ways to pass variable?

Comment: No, it's alert only ID value but when I give it's alert name, It's errors

Comment: `friend_data[id].name` is not a valid parameter name. (http://mothereff.in/js-variables)

Comment: friend_data[id].name  is show my friend name is sure if I call in correct ways because I used it to show name of my fecebook's friend again already.

Comment: You need to change the variable name only in your function.

Comment: please help me to solve it. I know my code is not correct but I want to show it to everybody for see it and help me to modifier it.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
function testId(id, name ){
    alert(id);
    alert(name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change for loop to this

```
for (var i = 0; i <friend_data.length; i++) {
results += '<div class = "clicker" id = "'+friend_data[i].id+'" onclick="javascript:testId(this.id,'+friend_data[i].name+')"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture" height="30" width="30">' + friend_data[i].name + '</div>';
}
```

Comment: While I add `+` to my code but I still get the same result, it's can't get name values

Comment: Did u change ur function function testId(id, friend_data[id].name ){ to function (id, name) ?

Comment: No I am not. It's still `function testId(id, friend_data[id].name ){
    alert(id);
    alert(friend_data[i].name);     
}`

Comment: change it to function testId(id,name) { alert(id); alert(name); }

Comment: I don't know why it's nothing is happened. but when I view it in firebug add-on , it's show `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list [Break On This Error] javascript:testId(this.id,Chan Vireak)` that when I checked it's not miss `)` . other one it's show ìd` value it's stop show. right ?

Comment: I think there is some problem because I see two closing brackets '))' in testId function. Can you edit your question with whatever update u have made till now. So that I can have a better look.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `+` in the code `'+friend_data[i].name+'`:

```
for (var i = 0; i <friend_data.length; i++) {
    results += '<div class = "clicker" id = "'+friend_data[i].id+'" onclick="javascript:testId(this.id, '+friend_data[i].name+')"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture" height="30" width="30">' + friend_data[i].name + '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, after I add `+` to my code but I am still can't get name value to function that I pass too .

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be defined as:

```
function testId(id, name) {
    alert(id);
    alert(name);
}
```

`name` will take the value of `friend_data[i].name`, when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
function testId(id, name ){
    alert(id);
    alert(name);
}
```

And then call it with: `testId(friend_data[i].id, friend_data[i].name)`

Or

```
function testId(friend){
    alert(friend.id);
    alert(friend.name);
}
```

Adnd then call it with: `testId(friend_data[i])`